# Transforming in a function to call

Tags: javascript, json

Im consuming a JSON file and its working fine, but how can i make this a function that i can call to active?

```
var getDescriptionLotoFacil = function (url, callback) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open('GET', url, true);
  ajax.responseType = 'json';
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var status = ajax.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(status, ajax.response);
    } else {
      callback(null, ajax.response);
    }
  };
  ajax.send();
};

getDescriptionLotoFacil('games.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err === null) {
    console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
  } else {
    var bets = document.getElementById('bets-description');
    bets.innerHTML = '';
    bets.innerHTML += data.types[0].description;
  }
});
```

Comment: You already have a function and call it. What exactly doesn't work here?

Comment: Can you explain this better: `but how can i make this a function that i can call to active?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just "wrap" this in a higher level function:

```js
const myFunction = function() {
  getDescriptionLotoFacil('games.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err === null) {
      console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
    } else {
      var bets = document.getElementById('bets-description');
      bets.innerHTML = '';
      bets.innerHTML += data.types[0].description;
    }
  });
}
```

You can also use a lambda syntax instead, replace first lines by:

```js
const myFunction = () => getDescriptionLotoFacil('games.json', function (err, data) {
   ...
```

then you call `myFunction()` and that executed the whole call.